# Disabling scroll on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have a SplitPanel with image inside. I set panel's AutoScroll, so if picture doesn't fit in panel, user can use mouse scroll. Now i want to scale the image by ctrl+scroll. It can be done by MouseWheel event of the panel. The question is: how to prohibit scrolling when ctrl is pressed? I tried using `HandledMouseEventArgs.Handled`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message sent to your `Panel`:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel {
    public bool ScrollDisabled { get;set;}
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
       if(m.Msg == 0x20a && ScrollDisabled) return; //WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
       //if(m.Msg == 0x20a && ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) return;  <--- or do this directly.
       base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

I forgot that your panel is docked inside your `SplitContainer` and can't assign it to a new instance. So here is the solution:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      //Suppose you want to disable scroll in Panel1 of your SplitContainer when Control key is pressed
      new PanelWndProc().AssignHandle(splitContainer1.Panel1.Handle);          
    }
    public class PanelWndProc : NativeWindow
    {
      protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
      {
        if (m.Msg == 0x20a && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) return;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This approach actually works. But includes creating a new class. Is there a way to do this using events?

Comment: @SkyterX No, to catch the message `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, you have to create a class inheriting from `NativeWindow` as I showed in my code. It's not very inconvenient I think so. All the built-in events don't work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to implement the `KeyDown` as well as the `KeyUp` event and check if `CTRL` has been pressed/released.

Once you have that you can disable the `Autoscroll` property on your splitpanel

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control)
  {
    splitpanel.AutoScroll = false;
  }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control)
  {
    splitpanel.AutoScroll = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: State of ctrl key can be checked without KeyDown/KeyUp events, by `ModifierKeys`. Disabling AutoScroll hides scroll bars, so i don't want to use that.

Comment: Well maybe I did not get your question correctly, what do you mean with "disable scrolling"? what happens if you scale the image?

Comment: I want scroll bars to 'freeze' while ctrl key is pressed, so i can resize the image without scrolling it. Show/hide scroll bars every time user presses ctrl is horrible.

Comment: What is the reason you want to "freeze" them? From my point of view when they are frozen, the scroll bar position will be incorrect, after you are done with scaling or needs to be udpated.

Comment: Maybe freeze isn't the right word. For example, i want to scale image up to 2x of its size, and if user continues scrolling nothing should happen. but if i don't disable scrolling, the image will continue to scroll without resizing.

Comment: So basically you want the same behaviour as in most image editing programs: you can scroll with the mouse wheel up/down. If you press CTRL at the same time the image will be scaled? And your problem is now is that when you do the resize, you are scrolling up/down at the same time?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that when i got MouseWheel event by panel, scroll is already performed.

Comment: Ok. What control exactly are you using to display the image which you have scrolling issues with?

Comment: There are two controls inside this panel: PictureBox and TextBox. And neither of them catches MouseWheelEvent.

Comment: Alright, I've found a user control which pretty much does what you want: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10096/PictureBox-with-zooming-and-scrolling The source is inclusded. Hope this helps